# Move SSIS package to production

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have created 50 views in the application database server and need to transfer data of all 50 views from the application database to a data tracking database on the daily basis. I created SSIS views on my staging database and worked fine. When I am going to deploy on the production server then I need to change the connection strings with production server details. Do I need to recreate the SSIS packages or changing the connection string will work in all 20 SSIS packages?

I am looking for suggestions to implement the best approach to do this. if you have any article please share.

PS: application database server and data tracking database server are different.

Comment: *"I am looking for suggestions to implement the best approach to do this. if you have any article please share."* Suggestions on what is "best" are off topic, for Stack overflow, as they generate opinionated answers. One method, however, is to use the Configuration Manager within Visual Studio to create multiple configurations, which change the values of Project Parameters that define the connection string of your Project level Connection managers.

Comment: https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2015/1/4/parameterizing-connections-and-values-at-runtime-using-ssis-environment-variables

Comment: Did you build your package using the 2012+ standard Project deployment model or is this a Package Deployment model?